# Dependency problem in Trusty

Tags: dependencies

```
shakil@shakil-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for shakil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/88.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 312 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 303158 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (3.13.0-53.89) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/perf', which is also in package linux-lts-vivid-tools-common 3.19.0-18.18~14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.89_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

shakil@shakil-Aspire-5733Z:~$
```

I have already tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove -f 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue attempting to update my `linux-headers` and it seemed that the issue was the multitude of not fully implemented updates. After a reboot, it updated without any issue. Considering you have 3 packages labeled as "`not fully installed or removed`," I'd reccommend rebooting and giving it another go.

Comment: the output doesn't say it's `not fully installed` it's a different situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

If that won't work then try:

```
sudo rm/var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: the OP states on different situation read the output closer.